# With Ordinary Least Squares, how do we know that when the partial derivative of RSS is 0, that is a minima?

Tags: optimization, least-squares, econometrics

To minimise the residual sum of squares, we take its derivative with respect to the beta parameters and set this to 0. But when a derivative is set to 0, this means it can be one of the minima or one of the maxima. In optimisation problems, you’d then check the result against second derivatives to determine which type you found.

In OLS, how do we know this optimising process results in a minima, let alone the global minimum?

Comment: You don't need to check derivatives at all: the values of the objective function along any transect through its critical point all form parabolas whose common vertex is at that point, whence it is a global extremum.  By considering what happens to values of the objective function as you move far from that point, it is obvious this extremum is a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Because OLS belongs in a subfield of mathematical optimization called convex optimization, and that field has some nice properties, such as

> every local minimum is a global minimum

Answer (score 1):

\begin{aligned}
\min\limits_{\boldsymbol{b}} \boldsymbol{e}^T\boldsymbol{e} = (\boldsymbol{Y}-\boldsymbol{Xb})^T(\boldsymbol{Y}-\boldsymbol{Xb}) \\
\end{aligned}
FONC:
let $\boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{Y}-\boldsymbol{Xb}$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{e}^T\boldsymbol{e}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{b}}} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial [\boldsymbol{Y}^T-\boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{X}^T]}{\partial{\boldsymbol{b}}} 2\boldsymbol{Iu} &= 0 \\
-2\boldsymbol{X}^T(\boldsymbol{Y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b}) &= 0 \\
\boldsymbol{b}^* &= (\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^TY
\end{aligned}
Second Order Sufficient Conditions: If we can show that objective is a convex function, then the FONC will lead global min. i.e. show that Hessian is Positive definite. (Note that suffiecent neccessary conditions is Positive semidef. hessian)

\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{e}^T\boldsymbol{e}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{b}}} &= -2\boldsymbol{X}^T(\boldsymbol{Y}-\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b}) \\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{e}^T\boldsymbol{e}}{\partial \boldsymbol{b}\partial\boldsymbol{b}^T} = \frac{\partial 2\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b}}{\partial \boldsymbol{b}^T} = 2\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X} \\
2(\boldsymbol{b}^T\boldsymbol{X}^T)\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b} =\\
2\boldsymbol{z}^T\boldsymbol{z} > 0 \ \forall \boldsymbol{z} \ne \boldsymbol{0} \\
where\ z = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{b}
\end{aligned}

therefore objective function is convex and FONC will give a global min.